# Accessing same variable from two different threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I know how multithreading works, how to use synchronized methods/blocks - but there is one thing that I can't find on web and it's not clear for me.

Let's say that we have have:

```
public class Parent {
    public Child child;

    public Parent(){
        child = new Child();
    }
}



public class Child{
    public int health;
    public int mana;

    public Child (){
        health = 100;
        mana = 100;
    }
}
```

This is obvious, that if I want to access `health` from two different threads, I need to make a getter like this:

```
public synchronized int getHealth(){return health;}
```

It's the same variable, when we touch it from two thread at once - it may break.
But what with the whole 'child' object? Can I for example make operations on mana on thread 1 and on health on thread two? In this way, I don't touch the same variable, but I'm still using 'child' on two different threads - so it may be unsafe. **Should I also synchronize while using 'child'?**

## Edit - an example;

```
gameloop.player_me.setX(5);
gameloop.player_me.setY(5);
```

I am changing X and Y from two threads - it's obvious that `setX` && `setY` are synchronized. But I'm also accesing other variables in `gameloop` from a third thread. Should I synchronize on `gameloop`?

Comment: when u **synchronize the method** you are actually synchronizing access to the variable as the method returns the variable...and can you plz post the code for multithreading....

Comment: You cannot find the answer on the web anywhere? That surprises me. Did you try the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)?

Comment: aww, this is actually a great website O.o. Thank you.

Comment: "Getter" is a design pattern.  It's not part of the Java language.  Calling a getter to accesses some field in some object has no different implications from any other method that accesses the same field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> This is obvious, that if I want to access health from two different threads, I need to make a getter like this:

No, it's not obvious. If you're concerned about thread-safety, then your fields shouldn't be public. In fact, they shouldn't be public, even if you're not concerned about thread-safety. And if they are private, then your Child class, as is, is effectively immutable since no method can modify any of the fields, so synchronization is not needed.

> In this way, I don't touch the same variable, but I'm still using 'child' on two different threads - so it may be unsafe. Should I also synchronize while using 'child'?

It depends. Are the two variables related to each other? Or should they always be kept in a consistent state? Does your method modify the state?

Assuming the Child class is mutable, if both fields are completely unrelated, you don't need to use the same lock when modifying each of them. If they are related and should be kept in a consistent state, then you need to use the same lock to access them.

Every detail matters. It's impossible to give a definitive answer on what should be done if all we know is that a class has two fields.

Taking your last example, for example, you should probably not have a `setX()` and `setY()` methods in the first place. You should rather have a `setCoordinates(Coordinates c)` method and a `Coordinates getCoordinates()` method, which would be synchronized. This guarantees that x and y are modified together, atomically, and that no thread will ever see the new X without seeing the new Y yet. and thus think the player is in a location where it should never have been. Encapsulation is key.

Answer (score 2):

A `synchronized` *method* implicitly locks on `this`, so no, two threads cannot simultaneously get health and mana because the same object is locked for both. You could, however, use different lock objects for both of them by using a `synchronized` *statement*:

```
class Child {
  private int health, mana;
  private Object healthLock, manaLock;

  public int getHealth() {
    synchronized(healthLock) {
      return health;
    }
  }

  public int getMana() {
    synchronized(manaLock) {
      return mana;
    }
  }
}
```